# Find a line of a file, extract part of it and replace in the same place in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have a large file with the following content (this is an extract of it):

```
Total execution time (hh:mm:ss.ms): 00:00:8,4880 (8488 mseconds)
Error  0.00044
Stage 1 execution time (hh:mm:ss.ms): 00:00:7,0430 (7043 mseconds)
Stage 2 execution time (hh:mm:ss.ms): 00:00:1,4450 (1445 mseconds)
Total execution time (hh:mm:ss.ms): 00:00:0,0170 (17 mseconds)
Number of variables   6
```

Those lines could be more than one time and with different values. I would like to replace for the mseconds value. So, the expected output is:

```
8488
Error  0.00044
7043
1445
17
Number of variables   6
```

I've tried this but I don't know how can I replace the extracted value in the line:

```
grep "Total execution time (hh:mm:ss.ms):" file.txt | cut -d " " -f6 | cut -d "(" -f2
```

And I also was thinking doing this for each case (Total, Stage 1 and Stage 2), but if there is something more practical I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier using `sed` (I use GNU sed, to be specific) to achieve the result:

```
sed -E '/execution time/s/.*\(([0-9]*) mseconds\)/\1/'
```

Keep only the digit part `\(([0-9]*) mseconds\)` in lines with pattern `execution time`. The `([0-9]*)` are used as backreference in order to output the desired number by using `\1`, and `\(` and `\)` mean literal parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you! that works! The only thing I had to add is the `-i` to replace the value in its corresponding line

Answer (score 2):

Could you  please try following.

```
awk '
/execution time/ && match($0,/[0-9]+ mseconds/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/ [a-zA-Z]+/,"",val)
  print val
  val=""
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Comment: @mjbsgll,could you please try above once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Your code works, but doesn't update the file content, only shows the result. Anyway I wanted to do the task using `sed` command. Still thanks for your help!